# Scanear rede Wi-Fi no Android

Tags: android, scanner

Estou tentando escanear todas as redes Wi-Fi que o celular normalmente pega. Minha intenção deste escaneamento é a seleção e conexão da rede desejada.
Cheguei a seguir o tutorial da própria Andriod [Wifi-Scan](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan). Mas o problema é que não aponta o erro, e não mostra o resultado.

Ou seja na linha `wifimanager.getResults();` tem resultado 0, a linha esta localizada no método `sucesso()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public LinearLayout linearLayout =null;
    public WifiManager wifiManager =null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutLinear);

        wifiManager = ((WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));

        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Boolean sucess =  intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED,false);

                if(sucess)
                {
                    sucesso();
                }else{
                    old();
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        boolean success = wifiManager.startScan();
        if (!success) {
            // scan failure handling
            inSucess();
        }

    }
    public void sucesso()
    {
        List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult scanResult:results) {

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            String text = scanResult.SSID;
            textView.setText(text);

            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            linearLayout.addView(textView);

        }
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("sucesso");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
    public void inSucess()
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("falha");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
    public void old() {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("old preview");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }

}
```

Grato a todos.